# Canon MP980 prints wrong colors

Tags: printer, inkjet-printer, ink

My Canon MP980 printer recently started printing color incorrectly.

At first, all colors were pinkish. I changed the color inks as some said this might fix it. Now green prints as a grayish color, and blue prints as purple. Red, orange and yellow appear to be OK.

What's the matter with my printer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you used official new cartridges, then the next likely thing is the jets are clogged.  Most printers come with a cleaning cycle - Canons have a normal and deep clean. You can find it in the printer drivers.

Answer (score 1):

I am using canon MX927. after using refill cartridge, the print out turning into bluish color. Initailly, I suspected the refillable cartridge or ink color have problem/ poor quality.

The problem lies on the driver. Mx927 has XPS version driver that supposed to give improve printing quality (not much difference). When I used original canon cartridge, I use XPS driver without problem. Thsi driver does not work well with refillable cartridge so you need to switch back to default canon driver. and wallahh the print out comes back to normal again.

Comment: Your spelling will make all Frenchmen groan.  :-)  http://www.dictionary.com/browse/voila